# Dismiss Progress Dialog and handle exception in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am having a trouble dismiss Progress Dialog if any exception occurs at `doInBackground` in my AsyncTask as it never reaches the onPostExecute and never dismiss the Progress Dialog which makes ANR.

**Below is the code for AsyncTask**

```
   private class checkAS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog dialogue;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute();
        dialogue.dismiss(); 

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Long Network Task
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute(result);
        dialogue = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogue.setTitle("Processing");
        dialogue.setMessage("Getting Profile Information");
        dialogue.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialogue.setCancelable(false);
        dialogue.show();
    }
}
```

My question is if any exception occurs at doInBackground how will I handle it and how onPostExecute will be called to dismiss the dialogue? I can not dismiss it on doInBackground. How to sync this up?

Comment: set all attributes of progress bar dialogue on onPreExecute() and dialogue.dismiss() onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Return something like string from `doInBackground`. If `Exception` came `catch` that assign string value `error` otherwise return `success`

```
private class checkAS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog dialogue;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogue = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogue.setTitle("Processing");
        dialogue.setMessage("Getting Profile Information");
        dialogue.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialogue.setCancelable(false);
        dialogue.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Long Network Task
        String result;
        try{
          result = "success"
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          result = "error";
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);  
        if(result.equals("error"))          
           dialogue.dismiss(); 
        else
           // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: should I return null in doninBackground or should I return result?

Comment: Yeah thats correct for one background operation however if I will have to call the same AsyncTask for 4 or 5 times in a loop, the number of progressdialogue's instance will increase and hence make the Application not responding. BTW are you the same Hariharan who sings?????

Comment: @Saty After `onPostExecute` complete call again same `AsyncTask`. that time you will not get responding.

Comment: That will be again a difficulty for me as I will have to track the index number and file name if I will try to do one by one from onPostExecute (when one finish start another).

Comment: @Saty Yes like that `onPostExecute` complete call another that's called one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating dialog dialog in onPostExecute method it should be in onPreExecute method.
try this.

```
     private class checkAS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialogue;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

 dialogue = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialogue.setTitle("Processing");
            dialogue.setMessage("Getting Profile Information");
            dialogue.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialogue.setCancelable(false);
            dialogue.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Long Network Task
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
 dialogue.dismiss(); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry wrongly posted...I actually created this code now just to demonstrate. In original code, its in onPreExecute. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        System.out.println("check user profile");
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress((e.getMessage()));
        }
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Toast.makeText(activity, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to dismiss dialog in `finally` block of `try catch` construct.

i.e.

```
try {
...
} catch {
...
finally{
//dismiss dialog here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first check whether the dialog is showing or not using this code you can check

```
 if(dialog.isShowing())
 dialog.dismiss();
```

And use Exception handling to avoid unknown Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
    private class checkAS extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

                   public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

                   private static final String TAG = "checkAS";

                   // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
                   private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 12000;

                   // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
                   private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 12000;

                   private int taskType = POST_TASK;
                   private Context mContext = null;
                   private String processMessage = "Processing...";

                   private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                   private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

                   public checkAS(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

                       this.taskType = taskType;
                       this.mContext = mContext;
                       this.processMessage = processMessage;
                   }

                   public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

                       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
                   }
                   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                private void showProgressDialog() {

                       pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                       pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
                       pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
                       pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                       pDlg.setCancelable(false);
                       pDlg.show();

                   }

                   @Override
                   protected void onPreExecute() {

                       showProgressDialog();

                   }

                   protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                       String url = urls[0];
                       String result = "";

                       HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

                       if (response == null) {
                           return result;
                       } else {

                           try {

                               result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                               Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                           } catch (IOException e) {
                               Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                           }

                       }

                       return result;
                   }

                   @Override
                   protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

                       handleResponse(response);
                       pDlg.dismiss();

                   }
private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:

                    HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(url);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    break;
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            //  display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return null;

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
    public void handleResponse(String response) 

    {    
    //display("Response:"+response);
        if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            JSONObject jso;
            try {
                //do your stuff
                }
            catch (JSONException e1) {

                Log.e(TAG, e1.getLocalizedMessage(), e1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            display("Could not able to reach Server!");
        }


    }
```

Comment: where is  handleResponse(response) method?

Comment: See @Boopathi I dont want such lengthy code for me I am just uploading some files to the server so as there will be number of files to be uploaded so I make a loop and call the AsyncTask one by one from it. Which is causing the issue. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of files you want to send the server?

Comment: i am asking what kind of file such information,any documents or video audio files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private class checkAS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialogue;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialogue.dismiss();
    }
       @Override
       protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(15000);
           } catch (Exception e) {}
           return true;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           dialogue = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
           dialogue.setTitle("Processing");
           dialogue.setMessage("Getting Profile Information");
           dialogue.setIndeterminate(true);
           dialogue.setCancelable(false);
           dialogue.show();
       }
   }
```